# Nodejs process crashed without an exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I write a log entry to the log when an uncaught exception occurred in my nodejs app.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    log.warn('Caught exception. Exiting. error: ' + err + ", stack: " + err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

But, couple of times today, the app had crashed without writing a log entry.

Both times the app has crashed when processing a similar request, so it mostly should be due to some issue with the app, not because someone killed it or some other external factor.

So, is there any way the app could crash without giving an uncaught exception?

Comment: It depends on how other events are being handled in the server.js file - events like 'error', 'clientError', etc. Can you share the file containing the above code bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to add `unhandledRejection` as well. As the [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) documentation is mentionning,

> The `unhandledRejection` event is emitted whenever a Promise is rejected and no error handler is attached to the promise within a turn of the event loop. When programming with Promises, exceptions are encapsulated as "rejected promises". Rejections can be caught and handled using `promise.catch()` and are propagated through a Promise chain. The `unhandledRejection` event is useful for detecting and keeping track of promises that were rejected whose rejections have not yet been handled.

Here is an example of how to use it provided by Node.js again:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});

somePromise.then((res) => {
  return reportToUser(JSON.pasre(res)); // note the typo (`pasre`)
}); // no `.catch()` or `.then()`
```