# Nodejs - how to track after errors?

Tags: node.js

Yesterday I deployed my first nodejs app everything was fine, I woke up today and I saw the server stoped because error with some package.
How can I track after all the errors, and make the server not to go down even there is some error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs process crashed without an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571377/nodejs-process-crashed-without-an-exception)

Comment: Use PM2 for live production environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) as a process manager

`npm install pm2 -g`

Good practice is generate a [ecosystem](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) config

`pm2 ecosystem`

ecosystem.config.ts

```
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'My application',
            script: 'npm',
            args: 'start',
            autorestart: true,
            instance_var: 'my-app',
            out_file: '/path/to/out.log',
            log_file: '/path/to/global.log',
            error_file: '/path/to/error.log'
        }
    ]
};
```

Also you can use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) instead of globally install pm2. You can start you app with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` (or `npx pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` if you like).

To see list of started processes and its statuses use `pm2 list` or `npx pm2 list`

Answer (score 1):

You can use nodemon to restart the node-server after crashing - see [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1221):

install:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

run:
    nodemon -x 'node app.js || touch app.js'

---

alternative this should also work:

```
npm install pm2 -g
pm2 start server.js --watch
```